# is_int, is_numeric, is_float, and HTML form validation

Tags: php, html, validation, int

A select field on my HTML form may yield 1 to 5 (integers). Using `is_int` rejects it every time, because the `$_POST['rating']` is viewed as a string.

After consulting the PHP Manual, it seems `is_numeric() && !is_float()` is the proper way to validate for an integer in this case.

But I want to be certain, so please confirm or fire away at my logic.

Comment: You're correct. That would be the proper validation mechanism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use `is_numeric()`, because user input always comes in as a string (as far as I know).

Another way to guarantee something is an integer is to cast it...

```
$id = (int) $id;
```

Comment: but it must be an integer. Why is `!is_float()` unnecessary?

Comment: I guess because `is_numeric(0.1)` is `TRUE` :)

Comment: I don't think you understand. I want to restrict user inputs to integers only. Decimal values should be discarded//prompt for correction. In this case I think `is_numeric()` alone is inadequate. Perhaps we are talking past each other?

Comment: @Andrew I think you may have misunderstood me. If I submit a number, e.g. `5.5`, `is_numeric()` will return `TRUE` because it *is* numeric. But you don't want floats, so we also ensure it is not a float with `is_float()` negated (which will return `TRUE` because it *is* a float). Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: If you submit a number, e.g. 5.5, `!is_float()` will return `true` as well because all inputs from a web form are strings, as you have said, and `is_float()` checks for literal type, i.e. `===`.  Perhaps `!is_float($input / 1)` would be better, because then it would typecast the $input to it's nearest type, which if there was a decimal would be a float, and division by 1 would return an integer if the number was whole.  Or perhaps just checking `is_numeric() && !($input % 1)` with no `is_float()` as % 1 should return 0 if it is a whole number integer.

Comment: Of course, it might just be better to force an integer regardless of input so long as it is numeric input by using floor or ceil or casting to int or whatever.

Comment: Years later, I came across this post. This is incorrectly tagged as the accepted answer. @Matt Gibson's answer below is the most correct. Use `filter_var`. Casting the value as an int will 1) only strip out letters or 2) do weird things. For example 'fds1fd2fdk' will change the value to '0'. filter_var is best for user input validation.

Comment: @Joao Incorrectly tagged as accepted answer? I think it would suit the OP's original task fine. Would you want letters in an integer range from `1` to `5`? What *weird* things would it do to those *valid* numbers? I do however agree that `filter_var()` has clearer intent and a bunch of other useful options. You could even use `filter_input()` with `INPUT_GET`, which I believe would be even better as you can avoid the `isset()` stuff normally found with checking for GET params.

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't have said incorrectly tagged as accepted. But when talking about input form validation, I just wanted to point out that this answer isn't the best and can present some bugs. When validating a form the values accepted should be both exactly what the user intends to enter and is allowed to enter. A misstype of 1.3 would resolve to 1 and pass form validation. But you're right about `filter_input` - probably the best solution.

Comment: @Joao You're right, but the OP is talking about a `select` element. Anything submitted outside of `1` to `5` has been tweaked by the end user, so I don't think it's a stretch to have undefined behaviour occur.

Answer (score 5):

I would probably use something like this:

```
$value = filter_var(
  $_POST['rating'], 
  FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, 
  array('options' => array('min_range' => 1, 'max_range' => 5)));
```

[`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) will return either boolean `false` if the value is non-integer or out-of-range, or the valid value itself (as an integer.)

Answer (score 1):

if you want to know if `$_POST['rating']` is an int before you even try to cast do use `is_numeric()` && `!is_float()` as you have. This will tell you if the string is an int or not. If you just cast to an int and there is a non numeric all the numbers before the first letter in the string is turned into an int.

```
x = 457h
print (int)x
```

outputs 457

```
x = h56
print (int)x
```

outputs 0

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following regular expression:

```
preg_match('/^[0-9]{1,}$/', $value);
```

I does validate digits with leading zeros though...

Comment: Could also use `/^\d+$/`.

Answer (score 1):

`is_int` requires the input content is a integer.
`is_numeric` requires the input content is a integer or a string including just `0-9`.

but I am wondering the result if I put a number that is bigger than `PHP_INT_MAX` as the parameter into the above 2 functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can always cast it as an int.

```
$rating = (int)$_POST['rating'];
```

This will remove the need to validate it (even though you should always validate form data).
It may reduce your steps is what I'm getting at.

Comment: If the input is: '10test' then the result of int() would be 10. In other words, a wrong user input suddenly gets interpreted as it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

If you're testing for digits only (what an integer usually is ;)), I tend to use ctype_digit instead of is_int. That way, you won't lose data through casting, and you can just use a string:

```
<?php
$_POST['foo'] = '42';
echo ctype_digit( (string) $_POST['foo'] ) ? 'yep' : 'nope';
```

That'll output "yep".

Comment: How do you lose data by running `is_numeric() && !is_float()`?

Comment: @Tomalak I think he was referring to casting, e.g. `(int) 'abc' // 0`.

Comment: @alex: I don't really get it. The OP wasn't casting.

Comment: Hi. Yeah, sorry, I was referring to the other answers where they use casting, which is filtering, not validation. is_numeric( $var ) && !is_float( ) should work as well.

Comment: @Tomalak From Berry's answer: *That way, you won't lose data through casting*.

Comment: @alex: Yes... that's the comment that I was referring to. The OP didn't mention casting, so why did Berry?

Comment: @Tomalak I'm guessing because other answers did. :)

Comment: @alex: Right ok.. so that brings me back to my original question. How do you *lose* data by casting? You still have the original variable. And if you cast to the proper type, you should have all the proper data in the new one, too!

Comment: @Tomalak I'm guessing he is referring to the common practice of casting to integer when you expect one, overwriting the original variable.

Comment: @alex: That's my point: casting does not overwrite the original variable.

Comment: Ok, but what if your input IS an integer (suppose it gets casted somewhere), then it seems ctype_digit returns FALSE according to the manual: "ctype_digit requires a string to be useful, so for example passing in an integer will always return FALSE."