# is_float not detecting float numbers

Tags: php, forms, floating-point, floating-point-precision

I am using `is_float()` to check if the number entered is float or not but it keeps throwing the `echo()` message when I enter `3.00`. Is there any other solution to it? Or am I doing anything wrong?

Here is my code:

**PHP:**

```
if(!is_float($_POST["gpa"])){
    echo "GPA must be in #.## format.";
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" name="gpa" />
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [is\_int, is\_numeric, is\_float, and HTML form validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5486926/is-int-is-numeric-is-float-and-html-form-validation)

Comment: Works fine for me! Please show us your input, current output and your expected output

Comment: 3.00 is my input @Rizier123

Comment: The input is always a string or array (if specified), so `is_float` will always return false and therefor the if condition is true. Use `filter_var()` with `FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT` instead.

Comment: are you sure there are no excess characters, like spaces around? Try `trim()`-ming the value prior to its usage

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Form inputs are always a string, so the if condition will always return the error message you specified. Make use of `filter_var()` instead.

```
if(filter_var($_POST['gpa'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) === false) {
    echo "GPA must be in #.## format.";
}
```

If you want to validate the format you need to use **Reg**ular **Ex**pressions.

```
([0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{2,2})
```

You could use RegEx alone and forget about `filter_var()`, since it does the same.

```
if(preg_match('/([0-9]{1,})\.([0-9]{2,2})/', $_POST['gpa']) == 0) {
    echo "GPA must be in #.## format.";
}
```

Comment: Will I have to use reggae to limit the entry to #.## format?

Answer (score 4):

try this :

```
$num = 2.6;

if($num === floatval($num)){
    echo 'is float';
}else{
    echo 'is not';
}
```

other way is regex:

```
$num = '345.56678';//post is string

$patt = '/^\d+\.{1}\d+$/';
$resp = preg_match($patt,$num);
if($resp){
    echo 'is float';
}else{
    echo 'is not';
}
```

Comment: Will I have to use reggae to limit the entry to #.## format?

Comment: floatval is not working for me for some reason but this does: `if($num == (float)$num)(echo 'is float';)` - it will not filter `int` thou (but you can create another if using the same trick and `(int)$num` )

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://ww.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php)

> Finds whether the **type** of the given variable is float.
>
> To test if a variable is a number or a numeric string (such as form input, which is always a string), you must use is_numeric().

By definition, your `$_POST["gpa"]` is a string, not a float. You can see this when you do `var_dump($_POST["gpa"])`

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to validate the float value in a string will be:

```
if( !filter_var($_POST["gpa"], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) ) echo 'error!';
```

Comment: Will I have to use reggae to limit the entry to #.## format?

Comment: yes, that's the only way, if you really need to do it. Or you can `round($n, 2)` it to trunk all extra digits